# EC2 Auto scaling to start instances, not launch them

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I think this is not supported or possible, but maybe someone has tricked EC2 into doing this.

I have a group of 10 instances that are appropriately configured for my task.

I want to turn them on/off automatically using autoscaling. As opposed to launching new instances from an AMI. I also want instances to never be *terminated* but instead just be shut down.

Is this even possible in EC2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this even possible in EC2?

No, not using their ASG product.

The whole point of using an ASG (and honestly, doing more or less anything on EC2), is that your individual compute instances should not retain any state that you can't easily and quickly re-create. This means:

- keep data in a database of some sort
- keep static assets in S3
- build a centralized logging solution to collect and analyze logs from all of your instances
- use a configuration management system (Ansible, Salt, Chef, etc.) to automatically configure your instances on boot and deploy your application.

The last point is likely most applicable to your situation. If you solve that one, you'll likely be able to use ASG as its intended to be used.